# Create a backup of a file in bash

Tags: bash

I want to write into a file in a bash script but I want to make sure that the file is backed up if it exists and I also want to avoid overwriting any existing backups.

So basically I have $FILE, if this exists, I want to move $FILE to $FILE.bak if it does not already exist, otherwise to $FILE.bak2, $FILE.bak3, etc.

Is there a shell command for this?

Comment: Moving files is done by the `mv` command - see _man mv_.

Comment: I don't understand why this question got a -4.
+1 for me, as it could be very useful for bash beginners.

Comment: However, something is unclear: What to do if `file.bak5` was deleted on purpose, but some `file.bak6+` exist ? I believe the OP would like to increase from last existing backup file. No answer covers this, but as it is not clearly explained in question, I may be wrong here...

Answer (score 2):

Using a function to find the next available name:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function nextsuffix {
    local name="$1.bak"
    if [ -e "$name" ]; then
        printf "%s" "$name"
    else
        local -i num=2
        while [ -e "$name$num" ]; do
            num+=1
        done
        printf "%s%d" "$name" "$num"
    fi
}

mv "$1" "$(nextsuffix "$1")"
```

If `foo.bak` already exists, it just loops until a given `foo.bakN` filename doesn't exist, incrementing `N` each time.

Comment: I have an existing function almost just like that. I used `-f` but `-e` is much better (can backup directories). Thanks.

Comment: I think your condition is missing negation: the loop will be entered **unless** the file exists

Answer (score 1):

You can just output to a file with a date.

```
FILE=~/test
echo "123" >> $FILE.$(date +'%Y%d%m')
```

If you want the numbers logrotate seems to be most ideal.

Comment: There will be issues if multiple files are created in one day. It would be better to use date + '%s'

Comment: Yeah I've thought of that. Depends how often it would run.

Answer (score 1):

```
cp "$FILE" "$FILE.bak$(( $(grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+' <(sort -n <(for fil in $FILE.bak*;do echo $fil;done) | tail -1 )) + 1 ))"
```

Breaking the commands down

```
sort -n <(for fil in $FILE.bak*;do echo $fil;done) | tail -1
```

List the last file in the directory which is sorted in numeric form

```
grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+' <(sort -n <(for fil in $FILE.bak*;do echo $fil;done) | tail -1 ))
```

Strip out everything but the digits

```
(( $(grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+' <(sort -n <(for fil in $FILE.bak*;do echo $fil;done) | tail -1 )) + 1 ))
```

Add one to the result

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, my function with changes inspired by @Shawn's answer

```sh
backup() {
    local file new n=0
    local fmt='%s.%(%Y%m%d)T_%02d'
    for file; do
        while :; do
            printf -v new "$fmt" "$file" -1 $((++n))
            [[ -e $new ]] || break
        done
        command cp -vp "$file" "$new"
    done
}
```

I like to `cp` not `mv`.